# Colours not enabled with JSCH

Tags: java, linux, ssh, jsch

I'm trying to create a simple Vt100 emulator in Java - which work with JSCH.
Colours are displayed (when I print them with echo for example). But when I open htop, the display is set to monochromatic (and I can't change it). I've looked in HTOP source code, and it comes from a check (ncurses, has_colors): the server think that colours are not enabled on my terminal.

This is of course not a server-side problem (working well with PuTTy).

Thanks.

Comment: What is the TERM environment variable set to within the session where you run htop?

Comment: channel.setPtyType("vt100"); So vt100 (and thanks for answer)